# Tap on a text in List and push to other screen(view) swiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

On my view, I have a List in which the last item is a toggle button and Text in horizontal stack. I want to add the action on some part of the text(This text is similar to the terms and privacy policy). but on adding the NavigationLink to move to other screen, it adds the disclosure indicator with the large space between text and indicator and click is working on the whole Row. Is there any other option to push to other screen in swiftUI? I am currently using Xcode 11.1

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the screenshot of how it is being shown with NavigationLink:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `Button`. This is the code that I used to make it work. I also added an image that changes when the user get back to the list.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var showTestView = false
   @State var imageName = "heart"
   var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: imageName)

                Button(action: {
                    self.showTestView.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Test")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showTestView) { TestView(showTestView: self.$showTestView, imageName: self.$imageName) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var showTestView: Bool
    @Binding var imageName: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.imageName = "heart.fill"
                self.showTestView.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The effect while presenting the `TestView` will be a little different of using `NavigationLink` but it is useful and works.

Comment: But I wanted the behaviour of pushing the new screen, not presented on current.

Comment: The only way to push another view is using `NavigationLink`. If what you want is to use 2 `NavigationLink`s on the same cell I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857516/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-navigationlinks-per-row-in-a-list-swiftui) that could be useful.